# I don't know how to translate when Comma is used in sentences when listing things

Tags: punctuation

There is a sentence

> This percentage is higher among women, managerial and professional groups and those aged 35 to 44.

It's confusing me

Because I am not really sure what is it from 1 to 3

1 there is 3 groups:
women / managerial and professional groups/ those (who are) aged 35 to 44

2 there is 2 groups:
Women / managerial and professional groups and those(from managerial professional groups) aged 35 to 44

3 there is 1 group:
Managerial and professional groups who are aged 35 to 44 and women.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "rule" that you can use, so you have to go with what makes most sense.  In this case there are three different classification types: Gender, socioeconomic status, and age.  So the natural (and correct) reading would be:

> The percentage is higher in each of the following three groups
>
> - Women
> - Managerial and professional people
> - People aged 35 to 44

The use of "and" conforms with this.  The first "and" groups managerial and professional into one item. The second and comes before the final item of the list of three elements.  It would have been clearer if the author had used the "Oxford comma":

> this percentage is higher among women *(comma)* managerial and professional groups *(comma)* and those aged 35 to 44.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be missing the [serial (or "oxford") comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma), which would go before the final "and" in a series of items. It is controversial whether it is required or not in general, but generally accepted to be required where it creates ambiguity to omit it. Here maybe there is some ambiguity, but not a lot.

The initial comma setoff for "women" makes it quite clear that women are one group.

That leaves "managerial and professional groups and those aged 35 to 44". If the author wanted that to be all one group, they would much more likely use something like "managerial and professional persons [who are] aged 35 to 44", with that "who are" being optional. So that means that "those aged 35 to 44" is a group. "Managerial and professional" is a grouping that goes together, plus it is not the final "and" in the series, so pretty clearly those are also one group.

That leaves you with three groups.

Nevertheless, a serial comma would have rendered it even less ambiguous by separating each of the groups with punctuation: "this percentage is higher among women, managerial and professional groups, and those aged 35 to 44"

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't know that a serial Comma can be skipped

Comment: @Youngho It should be added or removed as required for clarity, and there are many examples both ways. Whether it should be used when it neither helps nor hurts is controversial.

Comment: "generally accepted to be required where it creates ambiguity." - the serial comma is preferred when it _removes_ or _reduces_ ambiguity, surely?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thx, added "to omit it" to the end of that sentence